# If I'm using Route from Laravel, can I do ajax calls using the normal method?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

When using laravel routing I write my links this way:

```
mywebsite.com/category/product
```

But to call ajax I would like instead:

```
mywebsite.com?author=&article=
```

And for `_POST` then

```
mywebsite.com/php/includes/dostuff.php
```

(The previous links are only examples)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Laravel API documentation you could do something like 
`$query = $request->query();` 
to get all the url query ($_GET) items.

Source: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_query

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You just use normal routing when it comes to making ajax calls.. There is many ways you can go about it and two simple ways would be:

Set the post route for your `'/'` (Home page or root page) to aim at a controller if you dont have any other post requests that are made to the `'/'` page or route..

```
Route::post('/', 'AjaxController@WhatEverMethod');
```

If you already have other post requesting routes that point to `('/')` then you can put a if statement to see if the request is Ajax and if it is then use the Ajax controller else use your normal controller.

My second simple solution would be to set a dedicated route that will handle your Ajax calls so for example:

```
Route::any('/Ajax/', 'AjaxController@index');

 public function index(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->ajax()){
                return "Is an ajax call..";
            }
            return "Is not an ajax call";
        }
```

There should be no reason why you cant easily resolve this issue, Checkout laracasts, That might give you a good head start.